# Unit testing an async function in a loop gives an error of multiple calls made to -[XCTestExpectation fulfill]

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, combine, xctest

I wrote a unit test to test if my email validation regex works. This works well if I check one email address string in my test. This is my code which works:

```
func testValidEmail_showsAlertWithSuccessMessage_whenLoginButtonIsTapped() throws {
    // Given: Login view model configured with the mock email regex specified in the appConfigResponse.json
    let appConfigService = try XCTUnwrap(createDefaultMockConfigService())
    
    // Given: A list of valid email addresses
    let validEmails = generateValidEmails()
    
    let waitExpectation = expectation(description: "testValidEmail_showsAlertWithSuccessMessage_whenLoginButtonIsTapped")
    
    appConfigService.loadAppConfig { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self else { return }
        
        let appInfoManager = AppInfoManager(service: appConfigService)
        let viewModel = LoginViewModel(appInfoManager: appInfoManager)
        
        viewModel.$shouldShowEmailValidationAlert
            .drop(while: { $0 == false })
            .sink { _ in
                // Then: Verify the success message is displayed in the alert
                XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.emailValidationAlertText,
                               LoginViewModel.StringConstants.validEmailTitle)
                
                waitExpectation.fulfill()
            }
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)
        
        // When: Entering a valid email address and then tapping on the login button
        viewModel.emailFieldViewModel.text = validEmails.randomElement()!
        viewModel.didTapLoginButton()
    }
    
    waitForExpectations()
}
```

However, I have an array of email addresses to verify against and if I add a loop, I get the error: `API violation - multiple calls made to -[XCTestExpectation fulfill]`

I understand that this is due to the expectation being called more than specified.

I took some advice from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73817257/1619193) and added this code:

```
let waitExpectation = expectation(description: "testValidEmail_showsAlertWithSuccessMessage_whenLoginButtonIsTapped")
waitExpectation.expectedFulfillmentCount = validEmails.count
```

However, this still gives me the same error. This is my code with the loop

```
func testValidEmail_showsAlertWithSuccessMessage_whenLoginButtonIsTapped() throws {
    // Given: Login view model configured with the mock email regex specified in the appConfigResponse.json
    let appConfigService = try XCTUnwrap(createDefaultMockConfigService())
    
    // Given: A list of valid email addresses
    let validEmails = generateValidEmails()
    
    let waitExpectation = expectation(description: "testValidEmail_showsAlertWithSuccessMessage_whenLoginButtonIsTapped")
    waitExpectation.expectedFulfillmentCount = validEmails.count
    
    appConfigService.loadAppConfig { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self else { return }
        
        let appInfoManager = AppInfoManager(service: appConfigService)
        let viewModel = LoginViewModel(appInfoManager: appInfoManager)
        
        for validEmail in validEmails {
            viewModel.$shouldShowEmailValidationAlert
                .drop(while: { $0 == false })
                .sink { _ in
                    // Then: Verify the success message is displayed in the alert
                    XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.emailValidationAlertText,
                                   LoginViewModel.StringConstants.validEmailTitle)
                    
                    waitExpectation.fulfill()
                }
                .store(in: &self.cancellables)
            
            // When: Entering a valid email address and then tapping on the login button
            viewModel.emailFieldViewModel.text = validEmail
            viewModel.didTapLoginButton()
        }
    }
    
    waitForExpectations()
}
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly why you still get the error but you can verify this with prints end see how many items exactly is .fulfill called. What I'd suggest anyway is - move the publisher subscription out of the loop, and use .collect(validEmails.count) and then in the sink you'll have an array of all the elements sent to the publisher.